# How to open external url on form submit, in a modal on an HTTPS

Tags: jquery, html

When i submit a form (within a modal), i am redirected to an external site. How do i open the external site within the same modal??

my button looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="printCouponEvent(); $('form').submit();" class="icon-button"><span></span>Εκτύπωση κουπονιού</button>
```

And i want to load the external content in my div:

```
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can post the value to iframe with its source set to actual submit location

```
  <form target="IframeID" action="http://yoursite/url.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="123" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <iFrame src="" name="IframeID"></iFrame>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use iframe here as i am on an https